# How to get data from block and translate it?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, parity

I use web3js to send transaction to block. And save some information in it.

I find that Parity client can show the parameters directly.

But when I get the block data with JSONRPC, I can't figure out which is my data that I put in.

For example I get a block by hash, and the return is like this:

```
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": {
    "author": "0x00d190002eae6a467af8dc7ac3215b41028ac06f",
    "difficulty": "0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff7",
    "extraData": "0xd5830107008650617269747986312e31382e30826c69",
    "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
    "gasUsed": "0x31d67",
    "hash": "0xf8e135dbadc405d6bc16cb5a0e3ac8dbe560927ba96e3844fa9ec838aca475bd",
    "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "miner": "0x00d190002eae6a467af8dc7ac3215b41028ac06f",
    "number": "0x2ef",
    "parentHash": "0xaec5be937a53721e2fa1795408e81f01df4144e401d97e1d580deb29688c332d",
    "receiptsRoot": "0x4b68641d219b1d8e82adc485b1920db42b3eec1099c692ab52899779d3edbf61",
    "sealFields": [
        "0x8411ddd280",
        "0xb8410ba11be8900cea08c411b10bbe990a252187452f956ae8fb48851675499af011478f858f9d5a5f80b46bbf726f91f330fff2fbac240855c11e86beabf32335a200"
    ],
    "sha3Uncles": "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
    "signature": "0ba11be8900cea08c411b10bbe990a252187452f956ae8fb48851675499af011478f858f9d5a5f80b46bbf726f91f330fff2fbac240855c11e86beabf32335a200",
    "size": "0x4f1",
    "stateRoot": "0xabe536a30aa59d297b71984091c8d31c158ad2e7551dafb3fb5ff420313a4372",
    "step": "299750016",
    "timestamp": "0x59551c7f",
    "totalDifficulty": "0x2eeffffffffffffffffffffffffee242a91",
    "transactions": [
        {
            "blockHash": "0xf8e135dbadc405d6bc16cb5a0e3ac8dbe560927ba96e3844fa9ec838aca475bd",
            "blockNumber": "0x2ef",
            "condition": null,
            "creates": "0x2825f034088137cd65328112bd4b0d7906cb2f94",
            "from": "0x0048e5a10050c9b566ea23d0b1393d188ef950bd",
            "gas": "0x47b760",
            "gasPrice": "0x18e14af0",
            "hash": "0x9433191bb9a8cdeee26c68ae20f0c710c6b922238847da8dc29e45d2d5d2a870",
            "input": "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",
            "networkId": 8995,
            "nonce": "0xd",
            "publicKey": "0x1bc1dd59eeaeb546ffa85598378b1a1b623317dd231bfd65fdc19b0a13c379b77c7334d91973149f7d5246b65c6c8658aecd1162439af2776aceeb7f78b927c1",
            "r": "0x3e82009ebbe3b7d1559b44c6f7ac0e4a3e1f0d7399b21dbdbd3462382de50c14",
            "raw": "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",
            "s": "0x478c96ece0763d198c1dd1786796008038944e1d65939aa79eb7d2eb552beb2d",
            "standardV": "0x0",
            "to": null,
            "transactionIndex": "0x0",
            "v": "0x4669",
            "value": "0x0"
        }
    ],
    "transactionsRoot": "0x4107bfd073f20a1bf82939bc7d1058bd31b108d9830e5b6e0985361b62b578d9",
    "uncles": []
},
"id": 1
```

}

In these information, which is I input? Or is there a JSONRPC that can return the data which I input? I read some document but not get correct answer. Can you give me some advice? Thanks. :)

Comment: To get the dats sent along with txn you need to look at the txn message not block info.

Comment: Emmmmm.... What is txn? I read a tx in this JSONRPC, https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_signtransaction, do you mean it? So I need to sign my transaction to get the data which I save?

Comment: Maybe you mean transaction? But I call get transaction by hash also returns something like this... I think it not very useful... I will update the transaction information later.

Comment: What/how are you sending the information to web3?  Is `0x0048e5a10050c9b566ea23d0b1393d188ef950bd` your address?

Comment: @SawyerYes. It's the address of my account  which send transaction. I will put my web3js later. Thanks~

Comment: @YangYifei Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a project on github:
https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder

It can help you to exchange your tx data to readable data. But it need the ABI.

Follow the README of this project, I can get the input information which I sent to transaction.

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: And what if there is no contract call involved? Like a native (ETH) transfer?

Answer (score 0):

You can 'dissect' the result from getTransaction.  Here's an example for retrieving integer values that were stored...

```
        web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash, function(error, trans){
        let input = trans.input.slice(10);
        let sample = [];
        if (trans) {
            let sliceFrom = 0;
            let sliceTo = 64;
            for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                sample[i] = (parseInt(input.slice(sliceFrom, sliceTo), 16));
                sliceFrom += 64;
                sliceTo += 64;
                console.log(i+": "+sample[i]);
            }
        }
    });
```